# Unable to launch any EXE in WSL console

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

If I open a WSL console (by clicking the app icon in the start menu), then launch any Windows exe, it hangs. I can see new process appears in Linux side process list, but can't find it in Windows task manager.

However, if I launch WSL in any other console, including PowerShell, CMD (by calling `wsl.exe bash -l any_windows_program.exe`), or an embedded terminal in IDE, everything works fine.

Why?

---

Some background:

I'm using the KALI distribution from Microsoft Store. It worked several days ago, and I've not updated anything recently.

---

Edit:

I noticed that my explorer didn't work properly, either. Normally, when I create a new file or folder, it should appears in the explorer immediately. But today it didn't appear until I pressed F5.

I tried restarting the explorer, it stopped, but didin't restart, then all process windows freezed (didn't respond to mouse / keyboard actions).

A reboot fixes all these problems. It seems like a kernel or driver bug.

Comment: Works for me with `notepad.exe`. Which `.exe` have you tried? You must have changed something.

Comment: @harrymc I tried `cmd.exe`, `ping.exe`, `ipconfig.exe` and `explorer.exe`

Comment: Try using the full path: `/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe`.

Comment: You mention that this clears up after a reboot.  So was it a one-time thing, or does the problem recur?  Is there any chance that you are on a laptop that may have hibernated or been powered down before the problem started?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought that this *could* be related to a networking issue that occurs in WSL when the Windows host is hibernated or powered down with the "Fast Startup" option (which is also a form of hibernation).

If that's a possibility, there are two potential recommendations:

- Turn off Windows Fast Startup (under `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options -> Choose what the power buttons do`).
- After hibernating (if you must), exit Kali and issue a `wsl --shutdown` from PowerShell, CMD, or the Windows Start menu.

That said, the fact that it only happens when launching through the App icon is a bit suspect.  That could point to something in your `~/.bashrc`.  Running `wsl.exe bash -l any_windows_program.exe` skips the interactive startup (`~/.bashrc`) but does run the `~/.bash_profile` since you specified it as a login shell (`-l`).

If the problem comes back, try it with `wsl bash -li any_windows_program.exe` instead, to see if it's something caused by the interactive startup.

Comment: I've also tried first launch `wsl.exe` in powershell, then launch `xxx.exe` in bash interacting shell, it still works.

Comment: Usually I left my computer (desktop, not laptop) on 24*7 for torrent seeding, it never poweroff or hibernate, just reboot occasionally during windows updates, and the last update is long long ago.